# Why can my constant not be used to create my array?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I want to make an array that holds a number of tile objects (called `Tile`) but it's saying that my constant int, `numTiles`, cannot be used as a... constant int... what?
The code I'm having issues with is here (error on line 5):

```cpp
// Variables - Tilemap
const int tileSize = 32;
const int screenWidth = GetScreenWidth();
const int numTiles = screenWidth / tileSize;
Tile tilemap[numTiles];
```

The error I get is as follows: `expression must have a constant value the value of variable "numTiles" (declared at line 14) cannot be used a constant`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue as it looks like `numTiles` is definitely a constant int... Can someone explain what the problem is here?

Comment: It needs to be a compile time constant.

Comment: Can you explain what this means to me? I'm new to C++ and compiled programming languages as I've only ever worked with Python.

Comment: The value `numTiles` can only be decided at runtime due to the call to `GetScreenWidth()`. The compiler has no idea of knowing what value `numTiles`will have so it can not statically allocate the array `tilemap`. You have to use dynamic memory allocation or use a suitable container which does e.g. `std::vector`. But I suggest you take an online course or similar in C++ if this concept is new to you.

Comment: Change all those `const` by `constexpr`. (You should probably have error for `GetScreenWidth()`).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanations from everyone, you were all very helpful and I understand how to fix my issue now. I'll definitely look more into runtime/compile time to prevent these issues in future. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the people in the comments of the post for explaining this to me:
The variables are calculated at runtime when they need to be calculated at compile time (this was due to my usage of `GetScreenWidth()`, which obviously cannot run during compilation).